# Is it possible to include wget connection info in output file?

Tags: networking, logs, wget

Is it possible to include wget connection info in the output file?

I need connection info such as "Connection timed out, " "Connection refused," "Network is unreachable," and "No route to host," to be included in the wget output file for programatic logic choices.

Thank You.

Comment: That output is redirected to `stderr`, so you can redirect this one to stdout: `wget http://url > file 2>&1` or `wget http://192.168.1.23  &> file`

Comment: @Edgar Magallon Neither `wget https://url > file 2>&1` or `wget https://url &> file` seem to redirect the wget connection info to my output file. Are you positive the wget connection info is output to stderr by default? Thanks!

Comment: It appears that wget has the -o (output messages to file) and -a (append messages to file) options for this purpose. File Examples: `wget -o file -O file https://url` or `wget -a file -O file https://url`. Stdout Examples: `wget -o - -O - https://url` or `wget -a - -O - https://url`. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `wget` has the `-o` (output messages to file) and `-a` (append messages to file) options for this purpose.

File Examples:

- `wget -o file -O file https://url`
- `wget -a file -O file https://url`

Stdout Examples:

- `wget -o - -O - https://url`
- `wget -a - -O - https://url`